# Overlapping shadow effect remains on Navigation Drawer's NavigationView

Tags: android, android-fullscreen, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

I have refined the Navigation Drawer Activity project template of Android Studio, which uses **Toolbar**, **v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle** and **NavigationView** instead of the NavigationDrawerFragment (and layout/fragment_navigation_drawer.xml).

[image: Navigation Drawer in immersive-sticky when the drawer is closed]

It is perfectly working. Then, I go further. I have my Navigation Drawer project in **immersive-sticky** (full screen) mode.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (hasFocus) {
        View decorationView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorationView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawerLayout,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    ...

}
```

A problem has risen. The bands of overlapped shadow effect on the NavigationView which are derived from status bar (on the top side) and navigation bar (on the bottom side) remain still.

[image: When Navigation Drawer is opened]

[image: When Navigation Drawer is opened and sticky status and navigation bars are showed]

How can I get rid of them?

I reviewed sources of v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle or NavigationView of Android, but in vain.

---

## Updated:

Thanks for @lcw_gg's advice, I have gotten rid of the status bar's shadow completely (while the navigation bar's shadow remains). That is to set `android:windowFullscreen` attribute `true` in layout xml.

But I want to do this in Java code. I found a way and probably it is equivalent to the xml way:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

And with doing this, you don't need any more to set these two flags -- `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN` and `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` -- to the `decorationView`.

[image: shadow of the status bar has disappeared while that of navigation bar remains]

Still, I can't find the way to get rid of the navigation bar's shadow. I'm waiting for a solution.

Comment: What API levels does this issue occur on? Is it all of them or only post-Lollipop?

Comment: @PPartisan My device is 5.1.1 (API-22 Lollipop; Nexus7). I haven't examined other devices yet.

Comment: May be worth experimenting with `android:elevation` attributes in your `layout` `xml` files in that case. I've experienced similar woes in the past when I've forgotten about elevation.

Comment: @PPartisan Thank you for your suggestion, but it is sorry, even if I set `android:elevation="1000dp"` or `"0dp"` on the NavigationView, nothing change.

Comment: If it can help someone, I am working on an app with a navigation drawer and met this problem on a Sony Xperia 4.4.3, Nexus6 6.0 and Moto G 5.0.2. And I noticed that the shadow is always there, even though the app is in fullscreen mode. If you put a color on the background of your activity/fragment, the navigation bar shadow will appear in white.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the status bar on top, putting this line in the style file is working fine :  `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>`. I have absolutely no problem with the status bar shadow.

Comment: @lcw_gg Thank you for the suggestion. It is indeed very useful. The status bar's shadow has disappeared completely! While the navigation bar's shadow cannot be removed.

Comment: Would you be so kind and publish also your layout file? I am having similar problems as you do. Besides sticky immersive I also don't want a toolbar at the top, but only a floating action button that would open navigation drawer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

At last, I made it.

The solution is using **`FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS`** together with **`FLAG_FULLSCREEN`** to the [`android.view.Window`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html) object.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

This has gotten rid of both of the shadows perfectly.

[image]

*lcw_gg's comment was very useful clue to manipulating [`android.view.Window`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html). Special thanks to him.*

---

## Update for Android 11

Unfortunately, the problem returns when I update my phone to Android 11 (API-30). The above solution isn't effective any more. An alternate solution is [@AllanVeloso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51976986/3501958) using `app:insetForeground="@null"`

And I also got a new solution. **Just getting rid of `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE`** is it. This `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE` should be the root cause of shadow effects.

For my humble research on Google Developer or StackOverflow, the flag is always explained to use with `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN` and/or `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION`, but *there is no exact explanation about [`SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE) itself* other than:

> This means that the insets seen there will always represent the worst
> case that the application can expect as a continuous state.

So I used it with other two automatically. But that was the root of this problem. Just removing `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE` alone resolved this problem (even on Android 10 or earlier).

### Deprecation for those immersive FLAGs

As you know those `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_*` are deprecated from Android 11 (API-30).

You will use like below:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    WindowInsetsController windowInsetsController = decorView.getWindowInsetsController();
    windowInsetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(
            WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    );
    windowInsetsController.hide(
            WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() | WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars()
    );

    window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
} else {
    (...)
}
```

As google people (like [Chris Banes](https://youtu.be/acC7SR1EXsI?t=126)) explained `Window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)` is almost equivalent to `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN` and `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION` combine with `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE`. There is no problem at least about shadow effects.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! - I was struggling for maybe 20 full hours trying to get this working, research view attributes, trying to figure out why this navigation bar black transparency wouldn't go away on Lollipop+ devices.

Comment: At the end, I found amazing solution

Comment: You are a hero, my friend! ;-)

Answer (score 21):

The accept answer has a problem. Setting flags `FLAG_FULL_SCREEN` and `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` will make the insets of the window to be 0 and content may lay behind the system UIs.

It will work because `NavigationView`, which is a subclass of `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout`, listen to `onApplyWindowInsets` and `View.setWillNotDraw` to true when window insets are all 0.

You just need to add to your `NavigationView` this:

```
app:insetForeground="@null"
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent Java code way rather than layout.xml? I don't know why but `setScrimInsetForeground` method couldn't be used.

Comment: @hata The developers restricted those apis to the library. Reading the code if you set `NavigationView.setWillNotDraw(true)` no inset foreground will be drawed, but I think everything else will be drawed correctly. You may try this.

Comment: Hmm, though `app:insetForeground='@null'` worked well, I couldn't work `setWillNotDraw(true)` as intended. But thank you Allan.

Answer (score 1):

For those with the same issue as above, but want to keep the system status bar always showing (thus not using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN`), there is some additional work you have to do to prevent a weird content creep underneath the status bar on lollipop. I didn't notice the issue on kitkat when I tested it.

I was using two navigation drawers (left and right) and weirdly had only the LEFT one casting the shadow on the bottom. Once applying `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` as shown in the accepted answer, the shadow went away but then had the content creep under the status bar as well as the navigation drawer drawing on top of the status bar; all the way to the device bezel.

To fix that you must overwrite your theme in v21 styles.xml to include:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

This will move the content back below the status bar and also prevent the navigation drawer from drawing on top of the status bar.

In addition to the above entries in my v21 styles, my activity code looked like this:

```
// Fixes bottom navbar shadows from appearing on side navigation drawers
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attributes = getWindow().getAttributes();
    attributes.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;
    getWindow().setAttributes(attributes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **hata** i have succeed to completely hide system UI, by merging his original code:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

  if (hasFocus) {
    View decorationView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorationView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
  }
}
```

with the solution code added in `onCreate` of my Activity before calling `inflate`:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Apparently, the flag `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` was the missing piece to make the full screen work as expected on my device (API 21)